# DateTime format to get time in mm:ss:HH

Tags: c#, datetime

How to *format* a `DateTime` value in **C#**, to get just the time part in the format `mm:ss:HH`? I want the *minutes first*, then the *seconds*, followed by the *hours*.

Comment: `string result = MyDateTime.ToString("mm:ss:HH");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *formatting*, e.g. by direct `ToString`

```
  DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.Now;

  // ':' - let's escape : (in case you insist on : delimiter)
  // something like 01:07:13 
  string result = MyDateTime.ToString("mm':'ss':'HH");
```

or via *string interpolation*:

```
  string result = $"My strange time is {MyDateTime:mm':'ss':'HH}";
```

Comment: What if I do not want any delimiter, but just something like mmssHH? How to get that?

Comment: @user7461027: then don't put the delimiter into the *format string*: `string result = MyDateTime.ToString("mmssHH");` (or `string result = $"{MyDateTime:mmssHH}";`) and you'll get something like `"115413"`

Answer (score 0):

`$"{DateTime.Now:T}"`
or
`$"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss}"`

You can look on the patterns in a doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Please, stick to format: it should be `{DateTime.Now:mm:ss:HH}`

Comment: my bad,
then only this one `$"{DateTime.Now:mm:ss:HH}"`

Comment: but I can not think of a situation where such a format would be profitable

Comment: yes, the format is strange; however, OP *insists* on it: "I want the minutes first, then the seconds, followed by the hours"

Answer (score 0):

To get the date time in the format you requested use:

`YourDate.ToString("mm:ss:HH");`